# CakePHP FormHelper - Can't disable multiple checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I've got the following in my view:

```
echo $form->input('Category', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'disabled' => true));
```

But, the checkboxes aren't disabled...

Answer (score 0):

Try the checkbox() method in the form helper.  API link: http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelpercheckbox

Just change your syntax (I think it's just a wrapper around the FormHelper::input, but this should work):

```
echo $form->checkbox( 'Category', array( 'disabled' => true ) );
```

If that doesn't work, post the HTML that is output from your call.

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work. Posted a ticket on cakephp.lighthouseapp.com. See here: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/808-form-input-cant-disable-multiple-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass true as string like:

```
echo $form->checkbox( 'Category', array( 'disabled' => 'true' ) );
```

If this doesn't work use

```
echo $form->checkbox( 'Category', array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' ) );
```